# Why the depth of Ram or FIFO is always 2 times of the width of address in RTL design?

Tags: verilog

I saw lots of examples of ram and FIFO design, the depth of memory is always 2 time of the width of address:

```
parameter addr_width=4;
parameter ram_depth=1<< addr_width;
```

Why? If the width of the address equal to 4, then the depth should have 16 possibilities right? why use 2*4?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing `1<<addr_width` with `addr_width<<1`. The result is rather different.

`1<<addr_width` is in effect 2**addr_width. (or 2^addr_width whichever notation you prefer).